# Sending a string to client through sockets

Tags: c++, sockets

The following code is a snippet from server.c

```
void list(int s)
{
vector<data> getList = readContent();
string output = "";
ostringstream conv;

for(int j = 0; j < readContent().size(); j++)
{
    conv << getList[j].record;

    output += conv.str();
    output += "      ";
    output += getList[j].fName;
    output += " ";
    output += getList[j].lName;
    output += " ";
    output += getList[j].phoneNum;
    output += "\n";

    send(s, (char *)output.c_str(), strlen((char *)output.c_str()), 0);
}
}
```

readContent gives me an array of structs with values (record, fname, lname, and phonenum)

The current data in the array is:

1000 steve kit 212
1001 joe smo 12
1002 will walt 33

The following code is a snippet from client.c

```
    /* main loop; get and send lines of text */
while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin)) {
    buf[MAX_LINE -1] = '\0';
    len = strlen(buf) + 1;
    send (s, buf, len, 0);
    recv (s, rbuf, sizeof(rbuf), 0);
    printf(rbuf);
}
```

The sockets are correctly set up, but it's not sending data to the client to print, does anyone know what is going wrong?

Comment: you should check the return code of `send` and `recv`. Furthermore the functions do not ensure that the whole buffer will be sent or received so you have to use a loop for sending and receiving data. Additionally you always append data to `output` and never reset the value of this variable in the loop, i.e. after sending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`readContent` is reading the data from where? Because this line looks very suspicious

```
for(int j = 0; j < readContent().size(); j++)
```

Surely that should be

```
for(int j = 0; j < getList.size(); j++)
```

because otherwise you are going to be calling `readContent` multiple times.